# Angular Eventemitter is not working

Tags: angular

In angular 5, I have multiple components, for example, one is header component and other is a setting component and third is the calendar component.

When I emit an event from setting to header component, it works but when I go to calendar link it is generating an error like below

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent ->
>   TodoComponent]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HeaderComponent
>   -> TodoComponent]:

**code sample here**

Header.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TodoComponent} from '../todo/todo.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public todo:TodoComponent) {

    this.todo.change_company_logo.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Todo.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.css']
})

export class TodoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change_company_logo: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  constructor() {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  fire(){
    this.change_company_logo.emit("hi");
  }
}

kanban.component.ts file

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kanban',
  templateUrl: './kanban.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kanban.component.css']
})

export class KanbanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

route.ts file

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/compiler/src/core";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Routes, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {TodoComponent} from './todo/todo.component'
import {KanbanComponent} from './kanban/kanban.component';

const appRoutes:Routes = [
    {path:'',component:TodoComponent},
    {path:'kanban',component:KanbanComponent}
];
export const routing:ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

First-time default component is todo.component.ts and there is a button to fire an event to header component it's work when goto kanban link it gives an error in the console that was defined above this code.

Please, advise.

Comment: in which component do you bind your "fire" function to your "fire" button ?

Comment: You are injecting a component into another component via the constructor. You inject *services* into components, not other components. Move `change_company_logo` to a service, and inject that.

Comment: Actually, I want to send a value from one-component to other component using event emitter, and it's working from todo component to header but when clicking kanban link it gives an error. Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to inject a component in another component using constructor, In angular you can inject a service which is annotated as `@Injectable`. Please refer [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for component communication.

Answer (score 0):

@Output() change_company_logo: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

can be this

@Output() change_company_logo = new EventEmitter();

and this:

```
ngOnInit() {}
fire(){ this.change_company_logo.emit("hi"); }
```

to

```
ngOnInit() { this.fire(); }
fire(){ this.change_company_logo.emit("hi"); }
```

you forgot to call fire, you defined it but didn't call it

Comment: Actually, this fire function will call on the button click.

Comment: can you make a stackblitz out of this? its not very readable like this